# Поиск символа "\n" в байтовой строке через input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

Ребята.

Не могу понять, как через `input()` передать функции для поиска в байтовой строке символ `\n`.

После того, как переменная принимает значение из `input()`, она ведь имеет тип `str`? Но если я введу через эту функцию символ `\n`, то это будет два символа?

Ребята, как правильно принять значение через `input()`, чтобы искать символ переноса строки в тексте?

==========================================================================

```
#coding: utf-8

megatext_str = '''
- Знатоки подскажите как из строки типа "Привет" получить "\u0441\u043b\u0443\u0445\u0438"?
- На c это делается так: if (str == "Привет") str = "\u0441\u043b\u0443\u0445\u0438"
'''


megatext_bytes = bytes(megatext_str,encoding='utf-8')

def check_text_func(megatext_bytes):
            '''Функция проверки определенной искомой семиотической комбинации'''
            arg1_str = input('Что ищем?   ')
            arg1_bytes = bytes(arg1_str,encoding='utf-8')
            if arg1_bytes in megatext_bytes:
                        print('Found')
            else:
                        print('Didn\'t found')

check_text_func(megatext)
```

Answer (score 3):

В Питоне 3, `input()` не работает с байтовыми строками (`bytes`), эта функция возвращает текст (`str`—Unicode строка).

`input()` читает ровно одну строку из стандартного ввода. `'\n'` символ это перевод строки (один символ)—он никогда не встретится в строке, возвращаемой `input()`. Если `input()` вызов вернулся, то либо `'\n'` встретился во вводе, либо EOF (конец ввода).

Чтобы прочитать несколько строк сразу до конца ввода, можно использовать:

```
import sys

text = sys.stdin.read()
```

Чтобы проверить, есть ли `'\n'` во введённом тексте: `'\n' in text`.